# Disable VrPanoramaView fade in

Tags: android, android-studio, google-vr

I am using **VrPanoramaView** (v180) for displaying single mono (2:1, e.g. 3600:1800) 360-degree image. Image can vary through time and I want to update it by timer (but it is not video, just pictures). But when I use *loadImageFromBitmap*() the widget blinks black and then the image fades in. Is there any possibility to suppress this animation and just change bitmap?